# Django models: different methods on each instance?

Tags: python, django, import

Imagine I have code like this in (it's about the concept; this is example code):

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Monster(models.Model):
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    def use_unique_ability(self, target):
        ''' different monsters types will implement this differently '''
    def check_attack(self, player): # should I attack this player?
        ''' different monsters types will implement this differently '''
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SlimyMonster(Monster):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 3
        self.hit_points = 10
    def use_unique_ability(self, target):
        target.hit_points -= 2 * target.attack
    def check_attack(self, player): # should I attack this player?
        return player.hit_points < self.hit_points

class CaerbannogRabbit(Monster):
    ''' well, you get the idea '''

# many more monsters
```

Each monster has the same attributes and method names, but different values and implementation. `Monster` would probably be an interface in Java. Each monster type will override only some of the many methods.

This technically works, but it has some significant downsides:

- Each monster is a new database table with the same columns
- Because of that, I need a lot of queries to check for all monsters
- I need GenericForeignKey to reference individual monsters (instances of any of the model classes)

The other extreme isn't exactly pretty either. This is based on [dynamically mixin a base class to an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544983/dynamically-mixin-a-base-class-to-an-instance-in-python) (+[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320705/python-missing-class-attribute-module-when-using-type)) and [how to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path):

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from os.path import join
from inspect import isclass
from imp import load_source
from settings import PATH_TO_MONSTER_FILES

class InconsistentMonsterError(Exception): pass

class MonsterClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    attack = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 1)
    defense = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 10)
    method_file = models.CharField(max_length = 128) # it's a source file, not media file, so I'm using CharField
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MonsterClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            modul = load_source(self.method_file, join(PATH_TO_MONSTER_FILES, self.method_file))
        except IOError:
            raise InconsistentMonsterError('no file named %s' % join(PATH_TO_MONSTER_FILES, self.method_file))
        classes = [cls for cls in [getattr(modul, x) for x in dir(modul)] if isclass(cls)]
        if not len(classes):
            raise InconsistentMonsterError('file %s doesn\'t contain classes' % join(PATH_TO_MONSTER_FILES, self.method_file))
        bases = self.__class__.__bases__ + (classes[-1], )
        self.__class__ = type('NewClassName', bases, {
            '__module__': MonsterClass.__module__,
        })

class MonsterInstance(models.Model):
    cls = models.ForeignKey(MonsterClass)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
```

and for each monster a file like this:

```
# slimy_monster.py
class SlimyMonster(): # not a Model
    def use_unique_ability(self, target):
        ''' different monsters types will implement this differently '''
    def check_attack(self, player): # should I attack this player?
        ''' different monsters types will implement this differently '''
```

- The code seems... inellegant. It's complex, and it's like using `eval` (execute code based on an 'external' string)
- Every monster must be changed in two places: the database and a file (although I suppose I could define database values in the file)

Given these two options, should I use one of them, or something in between? I tend towards the second option, but I'm not quite satisfied.

Comment: I remove the notice about being off-topic. IMO, having two version of the same code tend to be opiniated, reviewing one version could be better (in fact you could probably have two questions). have you read the [faq] before posting ? This can help to decide if your question is on-topic or not. (I'm still hesitant to consider the on-topicness of the question)

Comment: Well, it's best practise for specific code so that seems okay. Can't find the two different versions things. Splitting it in two questions seems wasteful though; the answers to each are just doing to complement each other.

Comment: The version things is my personal preference, nothing off-topic about it, just they have a tendency to being opinionated (again this is my opinion). I have difficulty to judge the topicness of v1 vs v2 questions. Indeed your question seems okay, there are no vote-to-close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is inheritance as a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

In your subclasses, use the following Meta option:

```
class SlimyMonster(Monster):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def some_method_to_override(self):
        ...
```

This way the subclassing has no effect on the database side, only on the Python side.